# Very odd conversion error

Tags: c++, casting

What, exactly, is a (*) and how do you cast it?

```
"error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'char *[]' to 'char (*)[]'"
```

Trying to get a SmartPointer to take array values. Header:

```
template <typename T> class SmartPointer
{
private:
    T* myPtr;
    int* count;

public:
    T* Value();

    SmartPointer(const SmartPointer<T>& a)
    {
        myPtr = a.myPtr;
        count = a.count;
        ++*count;
    }
SmartPointer(T* ptr);
SmartPointer(T value) { myPtr = &value; count = new Int(); ++*count; }
~SmartPointer();


void operator =(T a);
operator T*();
    T* operator ->();
};
```

Relevant calling line:

```
SmartPointer<char[]> str = SmartPointer<char[]>(new char[20]);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C pointer to array/array of pointers disambiguation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation)

Comment: Your value constructor (`SmartPointer(T value)`) is doing something very bad - storing a pointer to the constructor argument, which will be destroyed with the constructor exits. You probably want to initialise it as `myPtr(new T(value))`, assuming the destructor is going to `delete` it when the count reaches zero. Although then you have exception-safety issues; personally, I wouldn't provide that constructor at all, and leave it to the calling code to clone objects when necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this class but I would think you want:

```
SmartPointer<char> str = SmartPointer<char>(new char[20]);
```

Or possibly:

```
SmartPointer<char> str = new char[20];
```

Comment: Thanks, it successfully creates the SmartPointer. Or, possibly almost successfully. That is to say, I now get a heap corruption error before the SmartPointer gets to deallocate...Ah, "Invalid Address specified to RtlFreeHeap( 00390000, 0040211C )".

Comment: So, yeah, thanks, and if I could upvote your answer, I would.

Comment: @Narf I see I misinterpreted your code at my first look at it. Now I'm not clear on exactly how you changed your code. Are you using your original copy constructor as it appears to be flawed. (When finished, both the source and target instance would refer to the same memory.) At any rate, it should be a simple matter to step through with the debugger to see if you can see what's happening.

Answer (score 3):

A `char*[]` is array of `char*`, while a `char(*)[]` is a pointer to an array of `char`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, you can use a program called `cdecl` ([available on the web](http://cdecl.org/)) to tell you, or [use these fun rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386599/i-dont-get-what-the-following-pointer-variable-declarations-mean-in-c/4388237#4388237) to decode types yourself.